# How to use Loops or Lapply to generate 100 new variables from a matrix?

Tags: r, loops, lapply

So, I have a data frame containing 100 different variables. Now, I want to create 100 new variables corresponding to each of the variable in the original data frame. Currently, I am trying loops and lapply to figure out the way out of it, but haven't had much luck so far.

Here is just a snapshot of how the data frame looks like(suppose my data frame has name er):

```
a b c d
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
9 0 1 2
```

and using each of these 4 variable I have to create a new variable. Hence, total of 4 new variables. My variable should be like lets suppose a1=0.5+a, b1=0.5+b and so on.

I am doing trying the following two approaches:

```
for (i in 1:ncol(er)) {
    [[i]] <- 0.5 + [[i]]
}
```

and alternatively, I am trying lapply as follows:

```
dep <- lapply(er, function(x) {
x<-0.5+er
}
```

But, none of them are working. Can anyone let me know what's the problem with these codes or suggest an efficient code to do this. I have show just 4 variables here for demonstration. I have around 100 of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ronak's answer provides the most efficient way of solving your problem. I'll focus on why your attempts didn't work.

```
er <- data.frame(a = c(1, 5, 9), b = c(2, 6, 0), c = c(3, 7, 1), d = c(4, 8, 2))
```

A. for loop:

```
for (i in 1:ncol(er)) {
    [[i]] <- 0.5 + [[i]]
}
```

Thinking of how R is interpreting each element of your loop. It will go from 1 to however many columns of `er`, and use the `i` placeholder, so on the first iteration it will do:

```
[[1]] <- 0.5 + [[1]]
```

Which doesn't make sense because you're not indicating what you are indexing at all. Instead, what you would want is:

```
for (i in 1:ncol(er)) {
  er[[i]] <- 0.5 + er[[i]]
}
```

Here, each iteration will mean "assign to the ith column of er, the ith column of er + 0.5". If you want to further add that you want to create new variables, you would do the following (which is somewhat similar to Ronak's answer, just less efficient):

```
for (i in 1:ncol(er)) {
  er[[paste0(names(er)[i], "1")]] <- 0.5 + er[[i]]
}
```

As a side note, it is preferred to use `seq_along(er)` instead of `1:ncol(er)`.

B. lapply:

```
 dep <- lapply(er, function(x) {
   x<-0.5+er
 }
```

When creating a function, whatever you need to specify what you want to return by calling it. Here, `function(x) { x + 0.5 }` is sufficient to indicate that you want to return the variable + 0.5. Since `lapply()` returns a list (the function's name is short for "list apply"), you'll want to use `as.data.frame()`:

```
as.data.frame(lapply(er, function(x) { x + 0.5 }))
```

However, this doesn't change the variable names, and there's no easy efficient way to change that here:

```
dep <- as.data.frame(lapply(er, function(x) { x + 0.5 }))
names(dep) <- paste0(names(dep), "1")
cbind(er, dep)
  a b c d  a1  b1  c1  d1
1 1 2 3 4 1.5 2.5 3.5 4.5
2 5 6 7 8 5.5 6.5 7.5 8.5
3 9 0 1 2 9.5 0.5 1.5 2.5
```

C. Another way would be using `dplyr` syntax, which is more elegant and readable:

```
library(dplyr)

mutate(er, across(everything(), ~ . + 0.5, .names = "{.col}1"))
```

Comment: Thank you Phil for such detailed reply. It helped me track where I was going wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You could directly add 0.5 (or any number) to the dataframe.

```
er[paste0(names(er), '1')] <- er + 0.5
er

#  a b c d  a1  b1  c1  d1
#1 1 2 3 4 1.5 2.5 3.5 4.5
#2 5 6 7 8 5.5 6.5 7.5 8.5
#3 9 0 1 2 9.5 0.5 1.5 2.5
```

Comment: Thank you so much Ronak! It works. I am novice at coding so still learning but that worked. :)